# Why is ts-node not compiling typescript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node

Why is ts-node not compiling and executing typescript file? It is used in terminal like "ts-node scriptfile" It just returns a blank line.  What is wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) so you should run `ts-node <script>`

Comment: That is exactly the way I'm using ts-node <script>

Comment: Do you have a tsconfig file setup?

Comment: No tsconfig file, where and how do I set it up? But when input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored anyway.

Answer (score 5):

`ts-node` is a typescript executor, not a compiler. If you run `npx ts-node script.ts` it will execute as typescript, without compiling.

To generate a compiled js file, try `tsc script.ts`.